In visual studio 2022 GoogleServiceJson there is no compilation mode
I have a new .net maui project and I installed the Xamarin.Firebase.Auth package via nuget to be able to set the "GoogleServiceJson" compilation action, the google-services.json file. I noticed that if I set the minimum Android version to 14 in the project properties, the "GoogleServiceJson" option does not appear, creating a new project without selecting the minimum version this option appears. There seems to be a problem related to Android34. The rest of the project works with Android34, but if I make this choice I cannot set the action that requires the Google file.
I tried setting the minimum Android version and wanted to set the build mode for the Firebase Google file as required.

Did you try to set the Android Version in the AndroidManifest.xml instead?
